# VMWare Fusion locks up when entering promisc mode

Tags: vmware, vmware-fusion

Using the following command will result in the VM guest locking up;

```
ifconfig eth0 promisc
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading more [docs](https://www.vmware.com/support/fusion6/doc/fusion-60-release-notes.html), it seems that VMWare Fusion requires user authentication when a guest machine enters promisc mode. This should result in a user dialog popup, but doesn't seem to happen.

As a temporary work around you can untick the "Require authentication to enter promiscuous mode" box in "Preferences > Network", but should only be used if you trust *every* guest VM.

Bug has been reported to VMWare [here](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2561944#2561944)